# OHLC and Volume Data on the same Panel using mplfinance

Tags: python, finance, mplfinance

Is there a way to plot the volume and OHLC data on the same panel?

I tried putting the panel IDs same for both but that only plots the volume data (I guess the volume data is plotted onto later, and hence replaces the OHLC data?).

```
    kwargs = {
        'type': "candle",
        'volume': True,
        'volume_panel': 0,
        'main_panel': 0,
        'mav': (6,9),
        'title': f"{self.meta['2. Symbol']}",
        'show_nontrading': True,
        'style': self.plotStyle,
        'addplot': adps
    }

    mplf.plot(self.ohlcv, **kwargs)
```

[Example with the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc5VG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mplfinance actually *is* plotting *both* OHLC and Volume.

The problem is that the prices and volume are being plotted *on the same y-axis* and, most likely, your volume values are several or many orders of magnitude greater than the prices.  Thus you don't see the prices.

The workaround for this is to plot either volume, or ohlc, separately using `mpf.make_addplot()`

(use `type='bar'` for volume, and `type='ohlc'` or `type='candle'` for ohlc data).  In the call to `mpf.make_addplot()` you then *may* need to set `secondary_y=True` (or it may work automatically).

---

Alternatively, your question gave me the idea to enhance mplfinance to *automatically* put the volume on the secondary axes if it detects that the ohlc and volume data are on the same panel.  Thus you can avoid the need to call `make_addplot()` in order to place one of them on the secondary axes.

This enhancement is in mplfinance version **v0.12.9b1**, so you will need to install that version.  With this enhancement, all you have to do is what you tried above, that is, simply set `volume_panel` and `main_panel` to the same value and everything should work automatically.

With this enhancement, there are two addition kwargs to `mpf.plot()` that you may find useful:

- `volume_alpha=` to set the opacity of the volume bars (in case you want them to be lighter or more transparent, allowing the ohlc data to be more apparent and/or stand out.
- `volume_ylim=` to be able to set the y-axis minumum and maximum for the volume, in case you want the volume bars to be somewhat smaller in appearance (by setting the `volume_ylim` maximum to a value significantly larger than the maximum volume).

Comment: Great, I got it to work this way just as I required to. 
However, would it not be advantageous to let a dictionary be passed with the standard kwargs for volume (just like a dictionary can be passed for the figure title?)

Comment: @Archit , Most kwargs that accept dicts, use the dict as kwargs to an underlying *matplotlib function* (ex: `fig.suptitle()` for figure title).  A few kwargs accept dicts because the keys relate to *a single mplfinance concept*.  Volume is not a general plotting concept, nor do it's kwargs relate to a single mplfinance concept. That said, I'm not opposed to the possibility of a dict for volume.  If you would like to discuss further, please open an [**issue**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/new/choose) on the mplfinance page, or email me at dgoldfarb.github@gmail.com

Comment: That does make sense, I was thinking along the lines of customizing the volume plot itself, but I think it'll make it that much clumsy and harder to maintain.